# Different alert dialogs for outputs in android

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

i was trying to print a set of pascal triangle rows in my alert dialog but it wont print on a triangle, it prints with each alert dialog for each row.
is there any way to print them in one triangle? help thanks:)

```
  public void onClick(View v) {
            String space = "";
            EditText id1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.id1);
            int num = Integer.parseInt(id1.getText().toString());
            print(num);

        }
        public void print(int n){
           String space="";
            int[] previousRow;
            int[] currentRow = {1};
            printArray(currentRow);
            previousRow = currentRow;
            for (int i = 2; i <= n;i++) {
                currentRow = new int[i];
                currentRow[0] = 1;
                currentRow[i - 1] = 1;
                for (int j = 0; j <= i - 3; j++) {
                    currentRow[j + 1] = previousRow[j] + previousRow[j + 1];
                }
                printArray(currentRow);


                previousRow = currentRow;
            }
        }



        public void printArray(int[] array) {

            String wow="";
            String space=" ";
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
              wow=array[i]+"" + ""+wow;


            }

            space="\n";
            AlertDialog(wow,space);



    }

    });
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what exactly you want to accomplish? Printing data with AlertDialog sounds like a pretty bad idea.

Comment: @Vesko  i want to print it in one triangle from the start up to the user input row, but it prints each row with its own alert dialog :( any suggestions?